# How to find specific number patterns in a data file

Tags: perl, awk, grep

I have a data file that looks like this

```
15105021   
15105043  
15106013  
15106024  
15106035  
15105024  
15105042  
15106015  
15106021  
15106034
```

and I need to grep lines that have sequence numbers like `1510603`, `1510504`

I tried this awk command

```
awk /[1510603,1510504]/ soursefile.txt
```

but it does not work.

Comment: `/[1510603,1510504]/` can be simplified to `/[,013456]/` i.e. it looks for any line containing any one of the characters in the character class anywhere on the line.

Comment: Are you trying to find numbers that lie between `1510504` and `1510603` numerically or numbers that start or end with those values or something else? Please clarify and post the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An shorter  `awk`

```
awk '/1510603|1510504/' file
```

Comment: Will it not match a number like `91510603`?

Comment: That is correct, and its what OP requested, a sequence numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Using egrep and word boundary on LHS since OP wants to match all matching numbers on RHS:

```
egrep '\b(1510603|1510504)' file

15105043
15106035
15105042
15106034
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the contents of your file the following should suffice

```
grep -E '^1510603|^1510504' file
```

If your [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) version does not support the `-E` flag, try `egrep` instead of `grep`

If you insist on [awk](/questions/tagged/awk)

```
awk '/^1510603/ || /^1510504/' file
```

Comment: You assume that the numbers are at the start of the line, but OP does not speechify that.

Answer (score 0):

Think this works:

```
egrep '1510603|1510504' source
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very poorly stated, but if you want to print all numbers in the file that *begin* with either `1510603` or `1510504`, then you can write this in Perl

```
perl -ne 'print if /^1510(?:603|504)/' sourcefile.txt
```

Comment: Or more succincly in Awk `awk '/^1510(603|504)/' sourcefile.txt`

Comment: I wonder if there's any chance the down voter would explain themselves?